# named route's URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-routing

HI,

I have a problem printing the named route's URL in production application. In one of my email template (email registration confirmation), am trying to append the confirmation url. this is the template snippet

```
<p>Welcome to example. To complete your registration, please click on the link below or paste it into a browser to confirm your e-mail address. You will then be redirected to example.com login page </p>

<p> <%= confirmlogin_url(:id => @user.id, :msg =>  @user.verification_code )%> </p>
```

and my named route looks like this

```
 match 'confirm_registration' => 'users#confirm_user' ,:as=> :confirmlogin
```

It works fine in the development environment, and the email is rendered with the confirmation url like this

```
Welcome to example. To complete your
registration, please click on the link
below or paste it into a browser to
confirm your e-mail address. You will
then be redirected to example.com.

http://localhost:3000/confirm_registration?id=16&msg=7fe548db-ab7d-3a8d-a87f-94ba89b0c29b
```

But in production environment i expected localhost:3000 be replaced with my actual domain name. But it still prints the local host url..

I just wanted to confirm this is the expected behavior..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this onto your production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "0.0.0.0:3000"
```

Use your hostname.